# .gitlab-ci.yml Override Variable Defined in appsetings.json

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to replace env variables used by AspnetCore by defining them in .gitlab-ci.yml file.

appsettings.json file looks like this:

```js
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConnection": "my-connection-string"
  },
```

Here are some things i tried.

Invalid Yml:

```
ConnectionStrings:
  DatabaseConnection: "my-connection-string"
```

Valid Yml (Not working):

```
"ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection": "my-connection-string"   
"ConnectionStrings::DatabaseConnection": "my-connection-string"
```

For last two i ger this error and as you can see it is all transformed into one long string instead of key value pair for env varijable:

> /bin/bash: line 87: export:
>   `ConnectionStrings::DatabaseConnection=Server=mssql,1433;Database=MyDatabase;User
>   Id=SA;Password=MyPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True':
>   not a valid identifier

I am using linux runner for CI.

Comment: Can you post a bigger part of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? It is a bit hard to follow exactly what you are trying to do. Are you trying to define a variable in `.gitlab-ci.yml` that you can use in a text file, or from the command line?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Can you post gitlab-i.yml file because I'm having a similar issue with passing environment variables across different stages?

Comment: you can see what i did in the commend on the sugested answer below

Comment: Check this alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77370551/9399171

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to replace the database connection depending on the environment. You could use some strategies like configure variables

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConnection": "$CONNECT_ENV"
  },
```

where you could have one per environment for instance `$CONNECT_INT, $CONNECT_QA, $CONNECT_PROD` and configure each one of these variables properly (variables part of .gitlab-ci.yml)

```
variables: 
    CONNECT_INT : "ConnectionStrings::DatabaseConnection=Server=mssql,1433;Database=DB_INTEGRATION_PROD;User Id=SA;Password=MyPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Or you could have multiple files per environment, `CONSTRING_INT.conf, CONSTRING_PROD`, and replace it depending on the environment.

Or you could replace the connection string using shell commands. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226005/how-can-i-replace-a-specific-string-within-a-line-inside-a-text-file

An example of a real project we're using [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n37tL.png)
[Real example of one project][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n37tL.png)

Comment: Thx i know this :) but i am wondering if there is a solution thats similar to what i am trying to do

Comment: what i have done is i have made appsettings.Gitlab.json and just changed ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT env varijable but this way i can not store passwords on Gitlab.

Comment: @DživoJelić You could store the pass in secret variables and call the command like `- call %FLYWAYPATH%\flyway.cmd migrate -user=%DBEVOUSER% -configFiles=%FLYCONF_INTEGRATION% -password=%FLYPASS_INT%`
The variable FLYPASS_INT is the password stored in secret variables so no developer could know the pass even with a 'echo $variable'. Like that? This command is intended to run the db migrations. Notice that developer role can't see the secret variable but roles maintainer and owner can see the secret variables.